# Is there some way to create a setup stage in express?

Tags: node.js, express

I would like to have an array called `res.locals.messages`, that I could use to store messages created in routes, such as "phone number added to user". Is there some way to create a setup-stage that is run before any routes, where I could create this array? Is there a better way of doing this?

I know about flash-messages, but I'm building a REST-protocol without sessions.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing, before my routes:

```
//setup.
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.messages = [];
    next();
});
```